# Number generation between 1 - 100 in JavaScript using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have encountered a small issue in my code I need my code to generate a number between 1-100 which it does however, I need for it to generate a unique number between 1-100 I have included my code below. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>
<p id="number"> </p>
<button id="button"  onclick= "random();"> Get Number </button>
</body>

<script>
function random() {
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = 
Math.floor(Math.random()* 100);
 }



</html>
```

Comment: "using jQuery"  Why?  This is a math problem.  Not a DOM problem.

Comment: Try this  Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1

Comment: Make it simple, This code will help you:
<script>
var generatedNumber = [];
function random() {
 var gen = Math.floor(Math.random()* 100);
    var generated = 
(generatedNumber.includes(generatedNumber) ? Math.floor(Math.random()* 100) : gen);
 document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = generated;
 generatedNumber.push(generated);
 
 if (generatedNumber.length === 99) {
  generatedNumber = [];
 }
 }
</script>